# Event management problems

Tags: civievent

1. My events will not appear on the website calendar
2. Unable to upload images to the event description page
3. When doing a test registration, I do not receive a confirmation email

Could you please review?

Link to registration for Leadership Givers Reception:
https://www.unitedwaydgco.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=74

Link to registration for Campaign Celebration Dinner:

https://www.unitedwaydgco.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=75

Thank you,
Colleen

Comment: Colleen, it is a best practice to limit each Stack Exchange question to one issue/question.  Each of your points above could be related, but there are a number of factors for each issue that could be resolved independently.  I would edit this question to handle only one of your above issues and then add two more separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar is not part of core CiviCRM, so I can't be 100% sure without looking at it, but the first issue may be that you didn't mark the event as "public".  If I were setting up a calendar like that, I'd want to limit it to events marked "public" in case I wanted to record other events that shouldn't go on the calendar.

Your other two issues could be so many different things that it isn't worth hazarding a guess without more information or access to your site.  If you are in touch with the company who built your site, you should contact them, or you might contact a [CiviCRM Partner](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).